# C# Enum Index Behavior

Tags: c#, indexing, enums

I stumbled over the following example code, but I could not really understand the behaviour behind it. I tried to find an explanation in the C# documentation, but wasn't successful.

```
enum Color { Red, Green = 3, Blue }
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((Color) 1);
        Console.WriteLine((Color) 2);
        Console.WriteLine((Color) 3);
        Console.WriteLine((Color) 4);
        Console.WriteLine((Color) 5);   
   }
}}
```

The output of the code is:

```
1
2
Green
Blue
5
```

It appears that Blue gets the index of Green+1, but that in indexing only works upwards and not downwards. So why does the indexing works like this?

Comment: Because that's how the designers of the language decided it to work. How would you make it work both ways? What if you had `{ red=1,green,blue=4 }`?  It's easy with the current rules to figure out that green is 2. In your world, what value would it get? You can't easily tell because there's a conflict.

Comment: It's described in the language spec [enum members](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/enums.md#enum-members): *the enum member `Red` is automatically assigned the value zero (since it has no initializer and is the first enum member);*

Answer (score 1):

Your code is effectively:

```
enum Color 
{ 
   Red = 0, Green = 3, Blue = 4 
}
```

It's just the compiler has filled in some of the values for you.  If you are unsure of what values go where, just initialise them all manually every time.  Sometimes, when an enum is large enough, you should probably do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I could only speculate as to why, but It doesn't make sense for indexing to work both ways.

Imagine if you were to override the last index to be max value, and you were to set the first index as 0. It would be ambiguous to what the values in between would be, should it be incrementing or decrementing?

If you wanted it to work downwards all you would have to do is start with the earlier index.  Specifying and index later gives you the options of using explicit indexes without having to worry about messing up the order